# I think there is a bug in the system

Tags: support, bug

I seem to be the victim of a bug that effects the reputation "score" system.  About two days ago I a question which was down voted that day and the day before it was asked, how can that happen?

Comment: Link to the question? I can't quite decipher what you think the bug is based on what you've written here.

Comment: According to the Stack Exchange API [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177483/i-would-like-to-ask-a-hypothetical-question-as-it-relates-to-html-css-and-java) (which is the one I assume you are talking about) was first downvoted two minutes after it was posted, at 11:28 PM UTC. It's possible that it looks wrong to you because of timezone issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at your reputation on the main site, and it looks like the balance is correct.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/109103/tom?tab=reputation

The only vote that you didn't receive was an initial down vote and rather than give you negative reputation, the casting of that vote only cost the voter and not you reputation.

Comment: Mike I am just a bit confused.  The question to which I refer is the question about HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  Next to the question it is down voted -5 how is that translated to -8

Comment: @Tom see [What's Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for the scores -- a down vote on a question is -2 reputation. You can see your rep history [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/109103/tom?tab=reputation&sort=time) and it shows you've lost -10 over time on that question which is in line with the number of down votes you've received.